# GitHub Pages Automation

Tags: github, github-pages, continuous-deployment, aws-codebuild, mkdocs

**Overview:**

I'm using [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) feature to host documentation. I'm working on a CI/CD process to automate the build so that when the source for the documentation is updated it automatically rebuilds the content and deploys to GitHub Pages.

**Details:**

So far, using [AWS CodeBuild](https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/), I've implemented the following:

1. Pulls down source from GitHub Repo
2. Uses [MkDocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/) to build and deploy to the special gh-pages branch using the "[mkdocs gh-deploy](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/deploying-your-docs/)" command.

This is done with command lines in the CodeBuild Buildspec. The reason I'm using commands is that I want to use [GitHub Deploy Keys](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/) opposed to creating user account (used as a machine account) that my team would need to manage.

I have it all working except what triggers the build. If the process was using a user account to authenticate then I can use [AWS CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/) which creates a [Webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) within the GitHub repo, and then notifications are sent via the Webhook to say that the master branch was updated, which would trigger a new build.

I'd like to implement a similar process but using the GitHub repo's Deploy Key. Any suggestions?